# SQL: a better way to include & exclude on the same field than, both, WHERE and NOT EXISTS?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have [**this query**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1f8af/19) which needs to, both, include and exclude on the same `role_id` field, so I'm calling the same table for both the `NOT EXISTS()` subquery and the `INNER JOIN`.

```
SELECT
    u.fname
    ,u.lname
    ,c.country
    ,c.postal
FROM [user] u
INNER JOIN company c
    ON (u.company_id = c.id)
INNER JOIN users_roles ur
    ON (u.id = ur.user_id)
WHERE ur.role_id = 3
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                     FROM users_roles
                    WHERE role_id = 4
                      AND user_id= u.id)
ORDER BY c.country, c.postal
```

This approach works, but seems kinda clunky, so I'm wondering whether there's a more standard (performant) approach that I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend running performance analysis on both queries, but you can also do this with a left outer join.

```
SELECT
    u.fname
    ,u.lname
    ,c.country
    ,c.postal
FROM [user] u
INNER JOIN company c
    ON (u.company_id = c.id)
INNER JOIN users_roles ur
    ON (u.id = ur.user_id)
LEFT OUTER JOIN users_roles ur2
    ON (u.id = ur2.user_id)
    AND role_id = 4
WHERE ur.role_id = 3
  AND ur2.user_id IS NULL
ORDER BY c.country, c.postal
```

This will end up with `NULL` in place of values for the `ur2` table if no matching rows in the table are found; if you assert in the `WHERE` clause that the value is `NULL`, it will exclude anything that *did* have a match.

Comment: It avoids subqueries. Depending on the data, the database software (SQL Server/MySQL/Oracle/Postgres/etc.), this query may receive a more efficient plan than the subquery-based alternative. *In general,* a `JOIN` is faster than a subquery.

Comment: This *generality* is not true with SQL Server. SQL Server converts `EXISTS` predicates into semi-joins.

Comment: That *may be*, but please note that I advised the question's author to run an analysis of both queries, and that I am answering the question as written (i.e. is there a different way to write the query).

Answer (score 1):

This one makes just one join, it uses grouping, sums the role_ids and checks on the aggregate result, the execution time on sqlfiddle is 6ms vs 24ms

```
SELECT
    u.fname
    ,u.lname
    ,c.country
    ,c.postal
    ,sum(ur.role_id)
FROM [user] u
INNER JOIN company c
    ON (u.company_id = c.id)
INNER JOIN users_roles ur
    ON (u.id = ur.user_id)
    and role_id in(3,4)
group BY u.fname, u.lname, c.country, c.postal
having sum(ur.role_id) = 3
go
```

Answer (score 0):

You could join `user_roles` just once and it might help performance a tiny bit. I cannot make up my mind right now which query I like more.

```
SELECT
    u.fname
    ,u.lname
    ,c.country
    ,c.postal
FROM [user] u
INNER JOIN company c
    ON (u.company_id = c.id)
CROSS APPLY (
 SELECT SUM (IIF(role_id = 3, 1, 0)) AS role3Count, SUM (IIF(role_id = 4, 1, 0)) AS role4Count
 FROM users_roles ur
 WHERE role_id BETWEEN 3 AND 4 AND u.id = ur.user_id
) ur
WHERE role3Count > 0 AND role4Count = 0
ORDER BY c.country, c.postal
```

This has the chance of being slightly faster because a single index seek on `users_roles` with range `role_id BETWEEN 3 AND 4` is enough to retrieve the roles. In your query, there were two seeks. On the other hand this query does some aggregates and computations. You'd need to measure.

I'm not convinced this is a nicer query. It is more complex than yours. I'll propose it anyway. You decide.